# Store tweets to a local MongoDB server

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparative-review, mongodb

I use NodeJS along with the MongoDB NodeJS Driver to store tweets into my local MongoDB server. In the following setup, mongos `insertOne` method gets invoked quite often by a socket event.

```
const MongoClient   = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const TwitterClient = require('node-tweet-stream');

const twitter = new TwitterClient({
    consumer_key: '',
    consumer_secret: '',
    token: '',
    token_secret: ''
});

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(client => {
    /**
     * Version 1
     */
    twitter.on('tweet', tweet => {
        client.db('twitter').collection('tweets').insertOne(tweet).then(rs => {
            console.log('tweet received', tweet);
        });
    });

    /**
     * Version 2
     */
    const tweetsCol = client.db('twitter').collection('tweets');

    twitter.on('tweet', tweet => {
        tweetsCol.insertOne(tweet).then(rs => {
            console.log('tweet received', tweet);
        });
    });
});
```

In version 1 `client.db('twitter').collection('tweets').insertOne(tweet)` is executed on every `tweet` event. Whereas in Version 2 the reference of the collection is stored in a variable.

Does the mongodb driver handle such repetitive calls like in version 1 and should I care changing the code structure to version 2 in terms of performance?

Comment: These code excerpts are so sketchy that I can't even tell whether the code is repetitive or not.

Comment: The question is: Is calling `client.db('news').collection('items')` over and over again efficient compared with storing `client.db('news')` and `collection('items')` into variables and use them in the actual method which gets invoked say every second.

Comment: Don't play charades. Show us your code. See [ask].

Comment: @200_success I edited the post.

Comment: Can you show us your schema as well.